# postfix evaluation algorithm

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-notation

here is my attempt for evaluation postfix evaluation

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class Stack
{
private:
    T *s;int N;
public:
    Stack(int maxn)
    {
        s=new T[maxn];
        N=0;
    }
    int empty()const
    {
    return N==0;
    }
    void push(T k)
    {
        s[N++]=k;
    }
    T pop()
    {
        return s[--N];
    }
    };

int main()
    {
        //postfix evaluation
        char *a="3+4*5";
        int N=strlen(a);
        Stack<int>save(N);
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]=='+')
                save.push(save.pop()+save.pop());
            if(a[i]=='*')
                save.push(save.pop()*save.pop());
            if((a[i]>='0' &&  a[i]<='9'))
                save.push(0);
            while((a[i]>='0' && a[i]<='9'))
                save.push(10*save.pop()+(a[i++]-'0'));
                    }
        cout<<save.pop()<<"  "<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but instead of answer 23  because 4*5+3=23,it gives me answer 5,as i understood,this code  gives me this result because,first it checks if there is + mark for i=0,which is not,then it checks if if it is *,this is also not,so it first push  0,then it evaluates 10*0+'3'-'0',which is equal to 3,(it would be pushed in stack),for i=1,a[i] is equal to 3,so it prints 3+, second pop   is undefined,so i think it is error,please help me to fix it

Comment: `3+4*5` is infix, not postfix (as a postfix expression it would be `3 4 5 * +`). If you want your input to use infix notation, you'll have to convert it before you can evaluate it as a postfix expression (using e.g. the [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)).

Comment: when i changed to postfix,it evaluates  something like -33 thousand something,why?

Comment: this number exactly -33685674

Comment: sorry betwen  numbers and  marks have to be space between them?

Comment: Tip: To help visualize what happens, write a `DebugPrint(Stack<int> const& save, char* a, int i)` method and call it first in your `for`-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with a little fix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Stack
{
private:
    T *s;
    int N;

public:
    Stack(int maxn)
    {
        s = new T[maxn];
        N = 0;
    }
    int empty()const
    {
        return N == 0;
    }
    void push(T k)
    {
        s[N++] = k;
    }
    T pop()
    {
        return s[--N];
    }
};

int main()
{
    //postfix evaluation
    const char *a = "3 4 5*+";
    int N = strlen(a);

    Stack<int>save(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]=='+')
            save.push(save.pop() + save.pop());

        if (a[i]=='*')
            save.push(save.pop() * save.pop());

        if (a[i] >= '0' && a[i] <= '9')
        {
            save.push(0);
            while (a[i] >= '0' && a[i] <= '9')
                save.push(10 * save.pop() + a[i++] - '0');
            i--;
        }
    }

    cout << save.pop() << "  " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/5osxt)):

```
23
```

Now, if you remove that `i--;` which I added, the code will be skipping characters in `a[]` because of 2 increments of `i`, in `a[i++]` and `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)`.

Without `i--;` the output is ([ideone](http://ideone.com/WWJm0)):

```
9
```

Comment: what if we will not put while statment into if expression?

Comment: Carefully review the code. If that doesn't answer your question, try running the program.

Comment: no it answered,just i have not put   while statment into if expression and so  asked